# Multi-variable Calc

Tags: calculus

I'm having problems approaching this question in my multivariable calculus class. The question reads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ball position, assume an initial velocity vector $\vec{u}_0$ at the origin, and double-integrate the acceleration equation to get the position as a function of time $t$ and $\vec{u}_0$. Then find the $t^*$ (in terms of $\vec{u}_0$) at which the third coordinate of the position becomes 0. At this $t^*$, the first and second coordinates are given by $P = (\sqrt{2},1,0)$, giving you two constraints on $\vec{u}_0$. You also know that the angle between the initial velocity vector and the ground plane is ${\pi}/{6}$, giving a third constraint. These three equations should be enough to solve for $\vec{u}_0$, and then you can substitute in your position equation to get your answer for (a).

For (b), the shadow's position is the intersection between the line passing through the light source and the ball's position, and the plane of the wall. So if you solve this intersection equation using the parameterized ball position, you should get the shadow position as a function of time $t$.